# Printing all the tabs in a dojo dialog on paper

Tags: javascript, printing, dojo

I have a dojo.dialog that contains 4 tabs, each showing a contentpane with some data on it.
I need to build a control to print all  those contentpanes to paper at once. How would you approach the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by sending the innerHTML of each ContentPane to a web service which generates a PDF that's sent back to the browser.